# How do I transform numbers into monetary numbers with PHP?

Tags: php

I have been looking all over the place, but only found the solution for:

12.58 format.

Which is not what I need.

Basically I'm looking to convert simple numbers into monetary numbers.

So if the number is 1, then it would show $0.01

10, then it would show $0.10

If 100, then $1

If 1000, then $10

If 1050, then $10.50

If 100040, then the format would change to $1,000.40

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [formatCurrency](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php) to format a currency:

```
$number = 1;
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo numfmt_format_currency($fmt, $number / 100, 'USD')."\n";
```

will output `$0.01`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot for your time and  help brombeer! Appreciate it.